# Mismatch between /reputation and epic badge tracker

Tags: bug, badges, daily-reputation-limit, deleted-accounts

There is a mismatch between what /reputation shows and my badge tracker for 'epic':

```
days represented 1269
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 42 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 45 days
earned 36 reputation from suggested edits
```

Meanwhile, the next badge tracker for epic shows 44/50:

> [image: epic badge tracker]

This appears to be caused by a user who had voted on a post of mine that was deleted (I saw a 'deleted user -10' show up in my rep history a bit ago).

So, in /reputation, it shows:

```
-- 2016-02-10 rep +200  = 47281     
-- 2016-02-11 rep +215  = 47496
```

while the reputation log on the site shows:

> [image]

The reason that I'm a bit below 200 was that I down voted several answers at 22:27.

> [image]

However, the reputation (and thus badge tracking) hasn't caught up with the reputation that wasn't assigned after the deleted user's vote was removed.

> [image]

You can see 21:34 down vote rep getting that rep 'back' with the 21:40 upvote (limited to +1 because of the rep cap).

However, the 22:27 down votes weren't 'recovered" with the 22:39 up vote to reset it back to 200 rep cap for the day, and thus a mismatch between the reputation cap information on /reputation and displayed for the epic badge tracking.  I believe that this is from a user being deleted who had upvoted a post that day, and the removal process isn't properly recalculating the reputation for the purposes of badge tracking.

I will note the possibility that I've confused all of this and /reputation and the epic badge tracker are looking different things, but if that is the case, then there's *still* a bug (just that this isn't the underlying cause).